# UITableView does not scroll cell to visible after UITextField becomes first responder

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` loaded with custom cells. Those cells have two possible states: A read-only state, and an edition state. I change between them by tapping the corresponding row in the table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomClass *aCustomClass = [self.model objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [aCustomClass setEdition:YES];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

The problem is that I need to set the cell's `UITextField` as first responder after tapping the row. What I've done is add the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (!cell)
        cell = ... // Create cell

    ...

    [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

All works well, but when the `UITextField` becomes first responder I want the table view to scroll the whole cell to visible. For that, I implemented a keyboard notification event like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGRect kbRawRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect ownFrame = [self.tableView.window convertRect:self.tableView.frame fromView:self.tableView.superview];

    // Calculate the area that is covered by the keyboard
    CGRect coveredFrame = CGRectIntersection(ownFrame, kbRawRect);

    coveredFrame = [self.tableView.window convertRect:coveredFrame toView:self.tableView.superview];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, coveredFrame.size.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.openCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is, the table view doesn't scroll the cell to the top position, as the last line indicates.

If I remove the automatic `becomeFirstResponder` call and tap the `UITextField` manually, all works OK.

Do you have any idea why this is happening and how could I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: why don't you add   [cell.textField becomeFirstResponder];  in didselectrowAtIndexPath  Instead of in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: It's not working. Only the text field is visible when I want the whole cell visible. Thanks.

Comment: Cant you add the difference between the TextField and the whole cell in pixels to your calculations so the whole cell is visible?

Comment: I can't. `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:` is not working at all. If I tap on the text field myself, then it is working.

Comment: try resignFirstResponder on textField first, then apply ScrollToRowAtIndexPath, let's see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, coveredFrame.size.height, 0.0);
```

should changed like this:

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -coveredFrame.size.height, 0.0);
```

Comment: Might want to elaborate on the cause and how the above fixes it.